# Unable to launch a Docker image with Blazor WASM

Tags: docker, dockerfile, blazor, blazor-webassembly, synology

Good morning,

I can't launch my (published) Blazor WebAssembly image on Docker. After having seen several tutorials which are in the same situation as me, I still cannot launch the image.

The goal is to put my Blazor WASM application on a docker present in a Synology NAS.
I don't fully understand docker and dockerfiles

Here is the location of the necessary files :
`\\PLASSYS-SERVEUR\Temporaire\Matis\Blazor\PlassysTools\PlassysTools.csproj`
`\\PLASSYS-SERVEUR\Temporaire\Matis\Blazor\PlassysTools\Dockerfile`
`\\PLASSYS-SERVEUR\Temporaire\Matis\Blazor\PlassysTools\bin\Release\net7.0\PlassysTools.dll`

Here are my error and file:

**Dockerfile :**

```
ROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 9321

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src

COPY ["PlassysTools.csproj", "./"]
RUN dotnet restore

COPY . .

RUN dotnet build -c Release

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app/publish


COPY --from=build /src/bin/Release/net7.0/wwwroot /app/wwwroot

RUN dotnet --list-sdks
RUN dotnet --version

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "PlassysTools.dll"]
```

**PlassysTools.csproj :**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly" Version="7.0.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer" Version="7.0.10" PrivateAssets="all" />
    <PackageReference Include="CsvHelper" Version="30.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <None Update="wwwroot\asset\Gas.csv">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
</ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

[Screenshot of my Docker application in Synology NAS (instant crash although my dll file is in the right location)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IL0Jp.png)

I changed my docker file several times before rebuilding it into an image, and I think the error may come from `COPY. .`
I create my image on my computer before sending it to the NAS

```
PS C:\Users\PLASSYS BESTEK\Desktop\Matis\Blazor\PlassysTools> dotnet publish -c Release -o ./publish
Version MSBuild 17.7.1+971bf70db pour .NET
  Identification des projets à restaurer...
  Tous les projets sont à jour pour la restauration.
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.400\Current\SolutionFile\ImportAfter\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Solution.targets(36,5): warning
NETSDK1194: l’option « --output » n’est pas prise en charge lors de la génération d’une solution. Si vous spécifiez un
chemin de sortie au niveau de la solution, tous les projets copient les sorties dans le même répertoire, ce qui peut en
traîner des builds incohérentes. [C:\Users\PLASSYS BESTEK\Desktop\Matis\Blazor\PlassysTools\PlassysTools.sln]
  PlassysTools -> C:\Users\PLASSYS BESTEK\Desktop\Matis\Blazor\PlassysTools\bin\Release\net7.0\PlassysTools.dll
  PlassysTools (Blazor output) -> C:\Users\PLASSYS BESTEK\Desktop\Matis\Blazor\PlassysTools\bin\Release\net7.0\wwwroot
  L'optimisation de la taille des assemblys peut modifier le comportement de l'application. Assurez-vous de tester aprè
  s la publication. Voir : https://aka.ms/dotnet-illink
  Compressing Blazor WebAssembly publish artifacts. This may take a while...
  PlassysTools -> C:\Users\PLASSYS BESTEK\Desktop\Matis\Blazor\PlassysTools\publish\
PS C:\Users\PLASSYS BESTEK\Desktop\Matis\Blazor\PlassysTools> docker build -t plassystools:latest .
[+] Building 0.1s (7/7) FINISHED                                                                         docker:default
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                    0.0s
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                               0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 957B                                                                               0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0                                               0.0s
 => [base 1/2] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0                                                            0.0s
 => CACHED [base 2/2] WORKDIR /app                                                                                 0.0s
 => CACHED [final 1/1] WORKDIR /app                                                                                0.0s
 => exporting to image                                                                                             0.0s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                            0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:c544492c75f93ca7d30b8667d9e1829138190c61979e92fa034b110900697622                       0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/plassystools:latest                                                             0.0s

What's Next?
  View a summary of image vulnerabilities and recommendations → docker scout quickview
PS C:\Users\PLASSYS BESTEK\Desktop\Matis\Blazor\PlassysTools> docker save -o plassystools-image.tar plassystools:latest
```

Thank you for those who take the time to help me <3

Comment: Where is your Web (http) Server in this?  A Blazor Wasm app ultimately runs on the clients, you only need to serve some static files.

Comment: try replacing `COPY --from=build /src/bin/Release/net7.0/wwwroot /app/wwwroot` ->  `COPY --from=publish /app/publish .`

Comment: @HH The Web server is located in the NAS, which will then be distributed as localhost throughout the intranet network.

Comment: @Rbee After the modifications it doesn't work either with the same error code